# how to sort mongodb document to appear document with certain key value to appear first,

Tags: mongodb

// i want to appear document with isFeatured:"true" at first

```
{        "_id": "625c13ea5c5d3f49f152783b",
        "name": "helmet 1",
        "description": "gold",
       
        "category": [
            "helmet"
        ],
        "price": "25000",
        "stock": 25,
        "user": "",
        "isFeatured": true // with this property to come first and "isFeatured:false" later
    }
```

Comment: Is there some special error you encountered with using [sort](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)? Please post your current attempt for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke [`sort` on the cursor](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#behavior) to sort the documents in `myCollection` on the `isFeatured` field in descending order.

```
db.myCollection.find().sort({ isFeatured: -1 })
```

Or [on aggregation pipeline query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{ $sort: { isFeatured: -1 } }])
```